# Request for all "Great Answers" for a specific tag

Tags: feature-request, badges

I think it would be a good idea to click on a given tag like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and be able to see all the "[Nice Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer)" for that tag.  Perhaps in descending order of Great, Good, and Nice Answer.

Showcasing answers this way may act as another incentive for the badge.

Comment: I don't think this would provide much value the existing ability to [view tagged questions sorted by votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes).

Comment: Good point... I edited the request to only show good answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jeremy notes in the comments, you can see the 10+ score questions in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) by just searching `[c#]` and sorting by votes.  This will obviously be in descending order of Great, Good, and Nice Question.

You can do this for answers by searching `[c#] is:answer` and sorting by votes.

If you really ***really***<sup>(yes, really)</sup> can't stand to see lower-voted posts and you page through the search results, you can also add `votes:10` to your search.  Check out [the search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for further ways to filter results.